# What to compute on school project "Distributed calculation"? (Useful)

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, distributed-system

**Before you read my question:** This topic fits to more than one StackExchange site (Mathematics, Software Recommendations, Software Engineering, Stackoverflow) so I putted it into most popular one. Move it please if you think it fits somewhere else better.

**TL;DR:** I need something useful what I can compute in simple distributed calculation app and what is not one of the most common things (DNA, fractals, ...)

End of semester is coming and I have an semestral work to do for subject "Distributed systems". The task is to make distributed system (across few physical devices connected by LAN). I have some options like distributed chat, shared variable, or what I prefer, **distributed calculation**.

My question is what can I compute on this. If I choose this topic I want it to be useful for something.
I do not  have knowlege of biomedicine (to compute DNA), advanced mathematics (eg. fractals) or similar stuff for what are distributed systems used mostly.

Do you guys have some ideas?

PS: It is not important but I will code it most likely in Node.JS or Java

Answer (score 1):

You can go with prime numbers calculation using brute force, i assume the value of your project is not in the efficiency of the algorithm, more on how you are distributing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Something that would be really interesting could be to execute queries using distributed calculation. Depending on your familiarity with databases and on the time you can devote, you can support as many types of queries as you find challenging and interesting (e.g distributed join).

To elaborate, you will have a number of nodes and some data that will be partitioned across those nodes and you will have a client performing queries on all those data. Your system will be able to answer those queries by doing some local computation on each node and then combining the results in a meaningful way to return the final answer.

To sum up, your project would be a **simplified distributed query engine**.